# How to deploy a node app from a monorepo built with Turborepo in Azure App Services using Github Actions

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, turborepo

I have a monorepo in Github that has been built with [Turborepo](https://turbo.build/). I want to deploy it in Azure App Service the backend app, but I'm having trouble finding out how to install turbo on Azure.

When the Github action starts running, it fails when doing npm install with this error:

`npm ERR! [turbo] Failed to find package "turbo-linux-64" on the file system`

I tried adding this step before building the app inside yml file:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Install Turbo CLI
    run: npm install turbo --global
```

but I still get the same error.

I also tried to install an Extension in App Service configuration but I don't find the option.

If I install turbo using ssh console, it won't persist, so it will fail again.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I tried adding this step before building the app inside yml file:

Instead of Installing the `turbo-linux-64`inside yml file, Install it directly in the `Azure Linux App Service`.

***Check the below steps:***

Create an `Azure Linux App Service` with `RuntimeStack` as `Node`.

> npm ERR! [turbo] Failed to find package "turbo-linux-64" on the file system

Navigate to your `App Service` => `Advanced Tools` => `Go` => `SSH`

[image]

Run the below command to Install the `turbo-linux-64` .

```cs
 npm install turbo-linux-64
```

***OR***

Open the `DebugConsole` directly with the below URL.

```cs
https://YourWebAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/
```

[image]

- Now check the installed `turbo-linux-64` version by using the ***`npm ls turbo-linux-64`*** command.

[image]

- Now try to run and Install the `npm install turbo --global` which you have tried in `yml file`.

[image]

- I am able to Install the `turbo` without any issues. Check the Installed turbo version using `turbo --version`.

[image]

> If I install turbo using ssh console, it won't persist, so it will fail again.

- If you want to persist the Installed turbo, then we can add a Startup script in the `App Service` =>  `Configuration` => `General Settings` section.
- Add the `npm install turbo-linux-64  --global` command in the startup script.

[image]

- Whenever the Application gets started the startup script will run automatically and Install the specified Packages.
- Save and restart the Application.
- Now check whether the turbo is Install or not using the same command `turbo --version` in SSH.
- Now deploy your application as usual from the `Deployment Center`.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborated answer Harshitha. I tried also to deploy the repo into a custom linux vm and I was still getting this error. 


Apparently it had something to do with installation if the `package-lock.json` file was included, removing it solves the problem.

That's probably not the solution, but I continue the research.